# How to split a string in Java with caret symbol '^' escaped?

Tags: java, arrays, split, caret

I am struggling with the string split method and the caret symbol (^) in java.

**Input:**

```
value1^value2^value3\^value3part2
```

**Expected output:**

```
[value1, value2, value3^value3part2]
```

Can anyone please provide a solution for this?

I have tried multiple solutions but with no success.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us what you have tried - at least one path.

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh `\d` is for digits. The question doesn't mention that the values are digits. Even if they were, this regex pattern still wouldn't avoid splitting on every `^` even if escaped with a `\\`.

Comment: This is what I have tried:

**String[] rowArray = row.split("\\^");**

and

**String[] rowArray = row.split("^");**

Comment: One question is whether the escape can be escaped - if the slash is doubled, is it still considered to escape the caret? BTW, your question shows a double backslash. Does that mean that a double backslash is an escape, or is this a mistake based on Java's String literal syntax?

Comment: The double backslash is how I am receiving the string (from a file in my case).
I can replace the double backslash with a single one if it can help.

Comment: So, are you sure that in the case of a double backslash the result shouldn't be `[value1, value2, value3\, value3part2]`?

Comment: Yes I am sure there should be only 3 values

Comment: What is important here is that can we assume that if `^` is preceded by any amount of ``\`` should it be always considered as escaped (or not). In other words, can ``\`` be part of value which was placed at the end? This would mean its purpose was not to escape `^`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic , let's assume this is my input:

**value1^value2^value3\^value3part2**

Comment: Are you certain there’s two backslashes?  Are you printing the String, or examining it in an IDE?  An IDE may display a single backslash character as two backslashes (like it would be written in code).

Comment: Yes correct in this case I am not concerned on the number of backslashes, I'm 100% sure I need to return a 3 values array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments it looks like you want to split only on `^` if it is not preceded by `\`. In that case you can use [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) mechanism `(?<!...)` which tests if part which we are trying to match is not preceded by regex described in `...`.

In your case you can use it like:

```
String[] values = yourLine.split("(?<!\\\\)\\^");
```

So you want to split

- on `^` (we needed to escape it `\\^` since `^` it is one of regex metacharacters),
- which doesn't have `\` before `(?<!\\\\)` - we needed to escape `\` twice, once in regex, once in string literal.